# looping through DevExpress GridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress

i am using the following to remove all list of gridControl but its not working giving error at **Rows**.no defination for Rows how can i loops throughs to remove all elements.

```
do
{     
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridControl1.Rows)
    {
        try
        {
            gridViewForVariableLinkage.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
} while (gridViewForVariableLinkage.Rows.Count > 1);
```

Comment: gridControl1.ItemsSource=NULL , isn't an option?

Comment: not options like that

Comment: what is the exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using for loop this way:

```
for (int i = 0; gridViewForVariableLinkage.RowCount > 1; i++)
{
   gridViewForVariableLinkage.DeleteRow(i);
}
```

Comment: Might want to use DataRowCount instead of RowCount in the event that grouping is applied to the GridView.